# Clustering plot in one-dimension data in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, cluster-analysis

I have a dataset with three columns and thousands of rows as shown below.

The number of `classes (clusters)` are 4 as shown in column three (`R, I, C, F`).

```py
row id     VALUE    CLASS  
   1        284         R  
   2        254         I
   3        184         C 
   4        177         F      

..........
```

- I am trying to get the cluster plot from the above data based on the 4 classes. The expected output is shown in the picture below.

[image]

**What I tried:**
Scatter plot in seaborn

```
from pandas import read_csv
import seaborn as sns

df2 = read_csv(r'C:\Users\jo\Downloads\Clusters.csv')

sns.scatterplot(data=df2, x="VALUE", y= "rowid",hue="CLASS")
```

[image]

Comment: you have only 1 variable, how do you even do a scatterplot

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have to say that the clustering algo is almost certainly doing absolutely what it is supposed to do. Clustering is non-supervised, of course, so you don't have any training/testing and you don't know what the outcome will be. You can feed in different features, and see what the outcome is. Also, you don't really share any code, so it's impossible to say for sure what is going on here. I would suggest taking a look at following links, below, and doing some more Googling on this subject.

https://github.com/ASH-WICUS/Notebooks/blob/master/Clustering%20-%20Historical%20Stock%20Prices.ipynb

https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/plot-k-means-clusters-python

https://towardsdatascience.com/visualizing-clusters-with-pythons-matplolib-35ae03d87489

Comment: The shared links still feeds the input data such as `prices_list` in first link. But as per given suggestion clustering don't have any training/testing ? My question was can plot cluster graphs based on `single dimension data` or single coloumn? We are sure that the plots can be achied with `two dimension data` or 2 coloumns data.

Comment: I don't think you can do a clustering experiment based on one column.